# How to handle trigger recursion

Tags: apex, trigger, recursion

I have two objects A(parent) and B(child) related by a lookup relationship. I  need to update records in object A using data loader. There is an after update trigger on object A which updates some fields on related records of object B. On object B as well there is an after update trigger which updates a field on parent object A. How can i handle recursion.

Comment: Have you seen this [post](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46790/how-to-avoid-recursive-trigger-other-than-the-classic-class-w-static-variable?rq=1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a Static variable(preferably Boolean) in an Utility class to determine the state of the run of the trigger.

So add a check at the initial of the code to look for the Static variable to be true and execute the code in Object A trigger. Before updating Object B records make the Static variable false and do the update.

So when the Object B trigger updates Object A, the Object A trigger will check for Static variable and it will be false and skip the execution(updating Object B).

Please refer cookbook [here](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/controlling-recursive-triggers).

Comment: http://salesforce-parth.blogspot.in/2015/09/recursive-trigger-class-in-salesforce.html

Answer (score 2):

Take a look [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66290/how-to-update-parent-object-in-trigger-without-risking-recursive-update-loops/66321#66321). It besically suggests to use static variable to determine if we have to execute the trigger or not.